# Help with modeling this hairstyle

Tags: modeling, hair

Edit: changed the title since "low-ponytail" sounds similar to "low-poly", so it might confuse people as to what I'm asking for. Sorry about that!

As the title suggests, I'd like to know the best method for creating this hairstyle: (original reference by undeadluciel on discord, I don't know what their other handles are)
[image]

I'm just having trouble getting the basic shape of the hair down, as I've never modeled anything like this before. Should I use curves? Should I sculpt the hair? I'm a bit stumped. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It would be helpful to give examples (if you have any) of already modeled hairstyles in the style you want this to emulate.  There are a lot of different ways to  model polygonal hair, and "low-poly" can mean different things to different people.

Comment: @jwrush hey there, could you clarify what you mean by "already modeled hairstyles"? If you mean stuff I've modeled, I unfortunately don't have any examples to show. If you mean other models online, I'm currently looking for models similar to the reference I've attached in the original post.  Also, I'm not necessarily asking for advice on how to model low-poly hair. I'll change the title though since "low-ponytail" is similar to "low-poly", and can therefore confuse others.

Comment: I guess he means do you have some 3D models close to what you're looking for

Comment: That's what I meant, but if you're okay with the answer, no need.

Comment: @jwrush Ah, thank you for clearing that up. I'll go ahead and add some extra references. Just give me a moment!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this way:

Begin with a rough lowpoly shape without any thickness:

[image]

Continue all around the head:

[image]

Give it a *Solidify* modifier and a *Subdivision Surface* level 1:

[image]

When you've done your best with this method, apply the modifiers, and work more in detail:

[image]

You will also be able to sculpt details on a highpoly version that you'll bake:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this out. :)